What is an <img> with ngSrc instead of src attribute expecting instead of base64 or blob URL?
I'm trying to use the NgOptimizedImage on a <img> tag, where the src attribute gets set to the path (or b64 encoded contents?) of a user-uploaded image. But, I either get an error complaining that it can't handle base64 encoded images or that it can't handle blobs.
At first I used regular src attribute (which worked perfectly!) but the IDE threw up a lint saying I should use ngSrc for better performance. Not that I believe my use case has any performance considerations, but I figured why not explore, since I assumed the API would be the same.
The suggested fix in the error logged is to just stop using ngSrc . I'm trying to figure out what is supported, other than just a plain old path to a local or remote file, and how can I idiomatically write the file preview logic so that it is compatible with this directive.
It's wild to me that I can't find any public facing documentation on these restrictions, or some greater warning that using ngSrc has significant caveats, or, god forbid, documenting what I can do with this directive.
See below for the two ways I populate the src path that is used in the <img>.
HTML:
<img
  [ngSrc]="src"
  alt="Uploaded Image"
  width="500"
  height="500"
/>

B64 error: NG02952: The NgOptimizedImage directive has detected that ngSrc is a Base64-encoded string (data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA0oA...). NgOptimizedImage does not support Base64-encoded strings. To fix this, disable the NgOptimizedImage directive for this element by removing ngSrc and using a standard src attribute instead.
  async previewImage(file: File) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
      if (e.target && e.target.result) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        this.imageSrc$.next(e.target.result);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

Blob Error: NG02952: The NgOptimizedImage directive has detected that ngSrc was set to a blob URL (blob:http://local_ip/9ed9c356-4066-4447-bc02-af3905be3dcb). Blob URLs are not supported by the NgOptimizedImage directive. To fix this, disable the NgOptimizedImage directive for this element by removing ngSrc and using a regular src attribute instead.
  async previewImage(file: File) {
    this.imageSrc$.next(URL.createObjectURL(file));
  }


EDIT: As a note, replacing assertNotBase64Image and assertNotBlobUrl with fake functions allows the images to appear as expected. Why have these asserts though...
Relevant PR, with a description offering no "why": https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/801daf82d119a39f21d26812b28c8551c58d841b

ng is part of the Angular Framework. ngSrc is just the Angular version of src to work within that framework. Aslong as you not using Angualr you should always use src.

But I am using Angular

You can see some docs here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgOptimizedImage  Seems like unnecessary overhead to me, but in cases where there's a lot of images loading at once, I guess this could be useful...   If you are going for optimizing load times you wouldn't be using base64 or blobs in the first place, so that may be why they don't support it.
